# Set background image using style in div

Tags: html, css, background

I am using HTML5 and CSS for designing a page. Will the following block of code set the specified image as `background-image` for two `<div>` with classes `.headarea` and `.leo`?

```
<div  class="headarea" style="background-image:url('C:\Users\Shanmugam\Desktop\Prathab\background\b (12).jpg)';width:100%">
    <div class="leo">
        <img src="C:\Users\Shanmugam\Desktop\Prathab\leo.png" width=90 height=95></img>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post the code Prathab.

Comment: am new to this stack.my mailid is prathabkumar22@gmail.com. can u please inbox me so that i will share u my code?

Comment: You can use http://jsfiddle.net for sharing the code.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't reference files directly from your computer's hard drive - try uploading them to a website like http://imgur.com and reference the pictures from there. Most people recommend not to use spaces in filenames, as well.

You've made a mistake here:

```
background-image:url('C:\Users\Shanmugam\Desktop\Prathab\background\b (12).jpg)';width:100%
```

You don't need the quotes:

```
background-image:url('C:\Users\Shanmugam\Desktop\Prathab\background\b (12).jpg');width:100%
```

Also, the classes `headarea` and `leo` don't do anything, from what you've posted. You can remove them.

Comment: thanks for the reply..imgur super reference.. i have tried the other way too. background-image:url('C:\Users\Shanmugam\Desktop\Prathab\background\b (12).jpg');    my question is can we add style within a <div> and modify the background?

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="C:\Users\Shanmugam\Desktop\Prathab\leo.png" width=90 height=95></img>
```

to

```
<img src="C:\Users\Shanmugam\Desktop\Prathab\leo.png" width=90 height=95>
```

IMG for the closing tag
not required

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.headarea{
    min-height: 380px;
    background: url('http://logovoi2014.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/TM-Priroda.jpg') no-repeat center top;
   position: relative;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}
.leo img{
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div  class="headarea">
    <div class="leo">
        <img src="http://catoftheday.com/archive/2014/AprilImages/10s.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```